# Spinx search normalized words

Tags: sphinx

I am test keywords with sphinxQL

```
call keywords ('azori', 'test', 1);
```

And get results

```
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| qpos | tokenized | normalized | docs | hits |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| 1    | azori     | a260       | 1550 | 1551 |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What means `a260`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a soundex representation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

seems like you have `morphology=soundex` enabled on the particular index

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology